# I'll [verb] it now vs. I'm going to [verb] now

Tags: time

I want to express the fact that I'm about to do something *immediately* (e.g : close a window, send an email ).

What's the most appropriate form of the future to use in English ?

- "I will close it now".
- "I'm closing it now".
- "I close it now"

Comment: Have you started yet?  The last one isn't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I will close it now" (future tense) = the next thing I am going to do is to close it.

"I'm closing it now" (present tense) = whatever I am doing (standing up, walking towards the window, closing it), you should understand it all to mean that I am closing the window.

"I close it now" (present tense) = describes the action of my closing it.

So, if you are about (future) to do it immediately, I suggest the first construction is most appropriate. You could use the second but it might suggest that you have already started the action.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, very clear explanation !

Comment: Thanks for your kind words :)

Answer (score 0):

I would write "I'm closing it now" or "I'm closing it right now", to emphasize further that I will do this action right away!